# How to use sendkeys function with ctrl+alt+c

Tags: c#, windows, sendkeys

I Have a menu item name calculator which is directly connected with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> keys. I Want to use send keys function to use that calculator with the click of my mouse.

I have tried like this

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(^%)C");
```

Comment: No yellin', please! - Also: What happened? What is the question?

Comment: Try this `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^%c");`, you don't require bracket.

Comment: THnks 4 replying bt it didn't work

Comment: Ahh... I used  capital letter, try now.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! You took off my headache dude! :)

Comment: No problem, I will add  as an answer so that it help programmers having  similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The method to use is

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^%c");
```

No parentheses and lower case **c**. (Upper case is interpreted literally as Shift+C.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't require brackets `()`, try this.

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^%c");
```